# Majorana wavefunction

Tags: condensed-matter, wavefunction, majorana-fermions

I'm trying to compute the wavefunction for a Majorana state in an nanowire/superconductor hybrid system, like [arXiv: Majorana Fermions and a Topological Phase Transition
 in Semiconductor-Superconductor Heterostructures](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4033).

I use the same ansatz for the wavefunction $\Psi\left(x\right) = Ae^{zx}$ and obtain the characteristic polynomial

$$
z^{4} + 4\left(\mu + 1\right)z^{2} + 8\lambda\Delta z + 4\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right) = 0\text{,}
$$

where $\mu$ the chemical potential, $V$ the Zeeman field, $\Delta$ the superconducting gap and I know that $u_{\sigma} = \lambda v_{\sigma}$ where $u_{\sigma}$ describes electron states and $v_{\sigma}$ describes hole states with $\lambda = \pm 1$.To solve the above equation I use the fundamental theorem of algebra:

$$
z^{4} + 4\left(\mu + 1\right)z^{2} + 8\lambda\Delta z + 4\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right) = z^4 - \left(z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4\right)z^3 + \left(z_1 z_2 + z_1 z_3 + z_1 z_4 + 2_2 z_3 + z_2 z_4 + z_3 z_4\right)z^2 - \left(z_1 z_2 z_3 + z_2 z_3 z_4 + z_1 z_3 z_4\right)z + z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 = 0\text{,}
$$

where $z_{i}$ are the roots. We see directly that

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{4} z_i = 0 \text{ and } \prod_{i = 1}^{4} z_i = 4\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right)\text{.}
$$

Now we can study different cases: the most interested case is when $z_{1/2}$ are complex and $z_{3/4}$ real. In this case we obtain

$$
z_{1/2} = a \pm ib
$$

and

$$
z_{3/4} = -a \pm \sqrt{a^{2} - \frac{4\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right)}{a^2 + b^2}}\text{.}
$$

In the publication they write that they have 4 boundary condition and 1 condition from the normalization.Okay, two from the fact that the wavefunction must localized at ends, so that I can write

$$
\Psi\left(0\right) = \Psi\left(L\right) = 0\text{,}
$$

and the same fact for the derivative of the wavefunction

$$
\Psi^\prime\left(0\right) = \Psi^\prime\left(L\right) = 0\text{.}
$$

Edit:

In the paper above they study two cases. In the first $\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right) > 0$ they say that they have 4 boundary condition and 1 condition from normalization but only 4 coefficients. I can explain that they neglect the two complex wavefunctions. However, in the opposite case $\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right) < 0$ they write that they have 6 coefficients and 6 Condition to solve the equation.

But now I'm completly confused! Why now 6 coefficients and 6 conditions?

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Comment: From the paper: "On the other hand, similar analysis for $C_{0} < 0$ always yields three roots with $\Re [z]<0$ either in $\lambda =1$ or $\lambda =−1$ channels resulting in six coefficients to match." Isn't the answer you were looking for ?

Comment: Yes, but at that time I didn't understand this sentence.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand the link to te presence or absence of Majorana mode either :-( But the problem is clear from the beginning: they have i) left/right waves, ii) spin up/down waves, iii) electron/hole waves, so in total 8 solutions for their differential equation: 8 in the bridge, 8 in the superconductor. There are also 8 continuity equations on the left of the normal bridge, 8 on the right. So the problem is complete I believe. I would ask Maple or Mathematica to resolve it, since the full solution is always ugly. Did you try some of these ? All the best.

Comment: As a warm-up, you can also do the same for a $s$-wave / $p$-wave / $s$-wave loop (the bridge being the $p$-wave superconductor in this case) and treat the problem in the quasi-classical approximation, where everything is simpler, since you have only first order differential equation. You can find some details about that in the following papers http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010206 and http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0210148 which are (to my mind) more readable than all the literature about the Majorana. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I solved this problem for few months. But thanks for the arXiv articles, there are very helpful!

Comment: so once gain, do not hesitate to publish your answer here, it mights be interesting for some other people. Also, it is always good to have well done calculations published somewhere. Have fun with the Majorana's.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of this problem is in principle very easy. Since

$$
z^{4} + 4\left(\mu + 1\right)z^{2} + 8\lambda\Delta z + 4\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right) = 0\text{,}
$$

is a fourth order equation I can solved this equation by the hand or with Mathematica/Maple and get 4 solutions. The interesting case is that with two purely real and two complex solutions. From this I can write down the general solution for the wavefunction:

$$
\Psi\left(x\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{4}A_{i}e^{z_{i}x}
$$

In the next step I must fix my boundary condition (here I consider just the simplest case with a semi-infinte wire, means my system starts at x = 0 and ends in infinity so that the right Majorana is vanishing). In this case I get three conditions:

$$
\Psi\left(0\right) = \Psi^{\prime}\left(0\right) = 0\text{,}
$$

and the normalization

$$
\int dx |\Psi\left(x\right)|^{2} = 1\text{,}
$$

means I must fullfill three conditions to fix the $A_{i}$. However, what we need is that $Re\left(z_{i}\right) < 0$ due to the fact that we need a decaying of the wavefunction into the wire. Hence, we can neglect all solutions with $Re\left(z_{i}\right) > 0$.

In the case that $\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right) > 0$ I get two real solutions with the same sign and two complex where the sign of the real part is opposite as the real solutions for each $\lambda$. Therefore we can not fullfill the conditions to fix the amplitudes.
In the opposite case that $\left(\mu^{2} + \Delta^{2} - V^{2}\right) < 0$ I get for each $\lambda$ two complex and one real solution for the $z_{i}$ with the same sign for the real part. Means here in this case I can fullfill my conditions for the wavefunction and get a very well result.