# Why is the ground energy of this spin-1 chain four-fold degenerate?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, spin-chains

In [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/2/26/010) the author found that the ground state of the following Hamiltonian

$$ H = \sum_{i=1}^{L-1} [S_i \cdot S_{i+1} - \beta (S_i \cdot S_{i+1 })^2] ,  $$

where $\beta $ is a real parameter, is generally fourfold degenerate (as long as $L$ is large enough). It is a numerically finding. But why? Why is it degenerate? If so, why is it four? Some people say at each end of the chain, effective there is a spin-$1/2$. But how can you get spin-$1/2$ out of spin-1?

Comment: That Hamiltonian is in the so-called 'Haldane phase' which is a well-known example of a Symmetry Protected Topological (SPT) phase. These are characterized by how certain symmetries (e.g. the $SO(3)$ of a spin-$1$) are projectively represented on the edge of the system (e.g. as the $SU(2)$ representation, i.e. a  'spin-$\frac{1}{2}$'). The mechanism by which this happens is 'symmetry fractionalization'. This concept is for example explained in a different context (the Kitaev chain) here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199647/unpaired-majoranas-in-the-kitaev-chain/235645#235645

Comment: You can get spin-1/2 out of spin-1 by **symmetry fractionalization**, which is a key feature of SPT phase.